# API Authentication in a Non-Interactive App

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am building a non-interactive application that works with the Valence API, and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how the authentication (specifically, the process of obtaining the User Id and Key) is supposed to work. My D2L administrator has provided me with my App Id and Key and I have been able to use them and the getting started sample to obtain my User Id and Key, but I cannot figure out if it is possible to get the latter in a purely non-interactive fashion.

I would like to know if this is possible at all, or if the interactive process of obtaining the API credentials is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the interactive process is required in order to obtain a User ID/Key. It should be possible to fake this by simulating the posting of the login form, if you are really desperate, but obviously this is an unsupported arrangement and would be very fragile and prone to breakage if anything changed in the login form.

Comment: This especially will be problematic if you're developing an app to connect with more than one back-end LMS, because the login form is highly site-customizable, and many customers have forms different to the default deployed form.